# Return type of out-of-line definition error with constructor initialisation list in C++ header file

Tags: c++, audio, constructor, rvalue, juce

I am making an object called "Clip" which loads audio from a file and stores it in a buffer, and will perform analysis. The parameters in the constructor are references to strings, a JUCE format manager and window method enum stored in another object.

I am using a split cpp and header file. As I am initialising and rvalue, I have used an initialisation list on the constructor, in the cpp file only, which I have seen to be generally recommended.

My problem is that Xcode shows a "Return type of out-of-line definition of 'Clip::Clip' differs from that in the declaration" error on the top of the constructor definition in the cpp file. What's weird is that it only shows up sometimes. Occasionally, the compiler instead shows a "Expected unqualified-id" error. Sometimes it shows no error at all.

What's the issue here? I am not using any different arguments in the constructor in the cpp file compared to the header file. Please help.

Clip.h file:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <JuceHeader.h>

class Clip
{
public:
    Clip(std::string &filePath, std::string &fileName, juce::AudioFormatManager                 
        &audioFormatManRef, juce::dsp::WindowingFunction<double>::WindowingMethod 
        &windowRef);
    ~Clip();
private:
    std::string path, name;
    int numSamples, numChannels, thisSampleRate;
    juce::AudioBuffer<float>* audioBuffer;
    juce::dsp::WindowingFunction<double>::WindowingMethod &windowMethodRef;
 };
```

Clip.cpp file:

```
#include "Clip.h"

// "Return type of out-of-line definition" error shows here
Clip::Clip(std::string &filePath, std::string &fileName, juce::AudioFormatManager 
    &audioFormatManRef, juce::dsp::WindowingFunction<double>::WindowingMethod &windowRef) : 
    path(filePath), name(fileName), windowMethodRef(windowRef)
{
    std::cout << "Loading new clip...";

    // Create file reader and load data into buffer
    juce::File file(path);
    juce::AudioFormatReader* formatReader = audioFormatManRef.createReaderFor(file);
    numSamples = juce::roundToInt(formatReader->lengthInSamples);
    numChannels = formatReader->numChannels;
    audioBuffer->setSize(numChannels, numSamples);
    formatReader->read(audioBuffer, 0, numSamples, 0, false, false);
}

Clip::~Clip()
{
    delete audioBuffer;
}
```

Comment: Xcode is not a C++ compiler. Only a C++ compiler can fully understand C++ code. It is not unusual for IDEs to misparse complicated C++ code. Is your C++ compiler compiling the above code without any errors? If so, that's the final word.

Comment: What happens after a clean? Shift + command + k